Homeomorphism $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus\{(x,0) : x \geq 0\}$
This was a problem in a previous exam of a past year, which I have not been able to solve. It basically asks for a Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus\{(x,0) : x \geq 0\}$ (euclidean topology).
This course is an introduction to topology, so no complicated tricks are expected to be used. At that point of the course compactness has not even appeared, so the problem is to be solved by basic means I suppose.
Just before this problem there's another problem in the exam that states that if A,B,C,D are topological spaces such that A is homeomorph to B, and C to D, then AxC is homeomorph to BxD (in the product topology). In our examens usually the problems that come before are to be used or are related to the next problems.
My first attempt was to split the subset into some sort of product, such that $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus\{(x,0) : x \geq 0\}$ = A x B, and both A and B homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$, but I wasn't able to do that (I think that this is the correct route intended for the problem).
The other attempt I made was basically try to express the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the union of all $S_r\setminus\{(r,0)\}$, where r is any positive number and $S_r$ is the border of the circle of radius r. I tried then some homeomorphisms (at class they showed the stereographic projection) with the union, but haven't been successful.
Any tip, hint or answer will be appreciated. Thanks!

One idea is to show that both spaces are homeomorphic to $(-\infty, 0) \times \Bbb R$ (to find a homeomorphism from this to the second space, think about complex numbers...). Another approach is to first show that $\Bbb R^2 \setminus {0}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times (0, \infty)$. In general it is important to be thinking about how you can "bend and stretch" one space to get to the other, and the interplay between this picture and a formal proof.

I am aware of the second homeomorphism, we have covered that. But how does this imply the one that I want to solve? I understand that $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus 0$ homeo to $S^1 x (0, \infty)$, and that this is "like" a cilinder without the base. But I can't see how to proceed with that.

It's then natural to ask: "what does $\Bbb R^2 \setminus {(x, 0): x \ge 0}$ correspond to under this homeomorphism"? This will be a set of the form $A \times B$, giving you something to work with..

No tricks are needed. What's needed is to write down an explicit formula for the homeomorphism: $$f(x,y) = \text{[something]}$$ and then (of course) to apply the formula in order to prove that it does indeed satisfy the requirements for the desired homeomorphism.

Thanks to both. I used the homeomorphism corresponding to $(x,y) \rightarrow (cos(\alpha), sin(\alpha), r)$, between $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus {(0,0)}$ and $S^1 \times(0,\infty)$. Then if we restrict this to $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus {(x,0): x \geq 0}$ we get that we are erasing $(1,0,x), x \in \mathbb{R}$ from the arrival. Thus this gives an homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2} {(x,0): x \geq 0}$ and $S^1 \setminus {(1,0)} \times(0,\infty)$, and we use the proposition and that $S^1 \setminus {(1,0)} \cong  \mathbb{R}$ (stereographic proj) and  $(0,\infty)\cong  \mathbb{R}$ with $e^x$.

Firstly, we can send all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the upper half plane with the map $f(x,y)=(x,e^y)$. Clearly, $f$ is an homeomorphism.
To send this half plane to $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus\{(x,0) : x \geq 0\}$ it is more convenient to consider polar coordinates. The upper half plane can be expressed as $\{(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)):r>0,\theta\in(0,\pi)\}$.
The idea now is to double the angle $\theta$. For that, consider the map $g$ defined by $$g((r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))=(r^2\cos(2\theta),r^2\sin(2\theta))$$ Notice that the angle of the elements in the image of $g$ will move between $0$ and $2\pi$, without ever taking on any of this two values. The ray $\theta=0$ corresponds with the positive real axis, so the image of $g$ is the desired final set (one can easily check that $g$ is a homeomorphism too).
An easier way of finding this last function is thinking of $\mathbb{R^2}$ as $\mathbb{C}$, as $g$ corresponds to the function $z\mapsto z^2$, which maps the upper half plane to all $\mathbb{C}$ except those with argument $0$, that is, the positive real axis.

Why to square the $r$ in the definition of the function $g$?

@jjagmath Only to make the function coincide with $z\mapsto z^2$ (which seems the more intuitive way to come up with it). The map with $r$ instead of $r^2$ works just as well.

Ok. I think it is more elementary to think about it in polar coordinates with just the idea of doubling the angle, which was more intuitive for me.
